# Tying up record types between implementations

Tags: ocaml

I'm stuck on how to implement this correctly. I have one file, Mytypes.ml, which contains the signature of a local and remote type which contain the keys for the cipher type - a record containing functions for signing and validating. I have two other files Cipher1.ml and Cipher2.ml

```
module Mytypes = struct
            type local_t
            type remote_t
            type cipher_t = {
                local_create : unit -> local_t;
                local_sign : local_t -> Cstruct.t -> Cstruct.t;
                remote_create : Cstruct.t -> remote_t;
                remote_validate : remote_t -> Cstruct.t -> bool;
            }
            type key_sets = {
                mutable locals : local_t list;
                mutable remotes : remote_t list;
                mutable ciphers : cipher_t list;
            }
        end

        module Cipher1 = struct
            open Mytypes
            type local_t = {
                secretkey : Cstruct.t;
            }
            type remote_t = {
                publickey : Cstruct.t;
            }
            let c1_local_create () = {secretkey = Cstruct.create 321}
            let c1_local_sign local data () = Cstruct.create 21
            let c1_remote_create public_key_data = {publickey = Cstruct.create 123}
            let c1_remote_validate remote data = true
            let create () = {
                local_create = c1_local_create;
                local_sign   = c1_local_sign;
                remote_create = c1_remote_create;
                remote_validate = c1_remote_validate;
            }
        end

        module Cipher2 = struct
            open Mytypes

            type local_t = {
                ekey1 : Cstruct.t;
            }
            type remote_t = {
                ekey2 : Cstruct.t;
            }
            let c2_local_create () = {ekey1 = Cstruct.create 321}
            let c2_local_sign local data () = Cstruct.create 12
            let c2_remote_create public_key_data = {ekey1 = Cstruct.create 123}
            let c2_remote_validate remote data = true
            let create () = {
                local_create = c2_local_create;
                local_sign   = c2_local_sign;
                remote_create = c2_remote_create;
                remote_validate = c2_remote_validate;
            }
        end
```

The error I always get is:

```
File "cipher1.ml", line 14, characters 19-34:
        Error: This expression has type unit -> local_t
               but an expression was expected of type unit -> Mytypes.local_t
               Type local_t is not compatible with type Mytypes.local_t 
        ocamlmklib returned with exit code 2
```

- line 14 is : local_create = c1_local_create;

Can anyone suggest a possible way forward?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not completely clear, but I'll assume that your example code represents three files named `mytypes.ml`, `cipher1.ml` and `cipher2.ml`.

The first thing to notice is that when you say `open Mtypes`, you're making available the top-level names of the file `mtypes.ml`. But there's only one top-level name in that file, `Mytypes`.

OCaml gives you a module for free at the outermost level of a file, so it's fairly rare to have a file containing just one module. This is true for `cipher1.ml` and `cipher2.ml` also.

The next thing to notice is that your `Mytypes` module is declaring `local_t` and `remote_t` as abstract types. Since you have no functions returning values of these types, there's no way for another module to create values of these types.

It's *certainly* not the case that other modules can declare their own versions of the types `local_t` and `remote_t` that they want to use.

From the way you've written your code, it's possible you want the definitions in `Mytypes` to be a *module type* rather than a module. You can declare a module type like this:

```
module type Mytypes = sig ... end
```

Then you can say that other modules have this type:

```
module cipher1 : Mytypes = struct ... end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. Yes, I shouldn't complicated matters by talking about *.ml and then showing code using module ... Apologies.

Comment: - update :Thanks for your help. Yes, I shouldn't complicated matters by talking about *.ml and then showing code using module ... Apologies. I have done as you suggested and turned everything into module type sig and module struct and everything compiles :) The only thing I omitted from my initial problem was another type which is a list of local_t. I guess it's best to do another question on this. Thanks very much for your help. Cheers